# Android Flashligt-App-Widget: How can I get an Camera-Instance within an IntentService

Tags: android, camera

I am developing an Android App in which where i can activate/deactive my Camera-Flash. Now my Question belongs to the following Code...

```
    public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvier {
    ....

          public class ToggleService extends IntentService {

            private Camera camera               = null;
            private boolean isFlashOn           = false;
            private boolean hasFlash            = false;
            private Camera.Parameters params    = null;

            private RemoteViews updateViews     = null;

            public ToggleService() {super("AppWidget$ToggleService");}

           protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
              Log.d("####","ToggleService.onHandleIntent()");
              ComponentName me = new ComponentName(this, AppWidget.class);
              AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
              mgr.updateAppWidget(me, buildUpdate(this));
    }

        private RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context) {
            Log.d("####","ToggleService.buildUpdate()");
            updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);


            if(camera == null) {
                 try{
                 camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            }catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ","" +e.getMessage());
            }


             }


            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppWidget.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent,0);

        //Widget image registry by ClickListener
           updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_bulbOff,pi);
           return updateViews;
    }

          }

    }
```

If i'm running my App, then make an Widget on the HomeScreen the following ERROR occur: Fail to connect to camera service...

Can anyone of you help me ...

Comment: have You set permissions and feature inside the manifest?

Comment: Yes I did it... I solve the problem by write an new class in which I declared the Camera,Parameter and each attribute which belongs to them as static variables ...